# jQuery: only run the callback function once after all the event changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This is my sample code:

```
var contents = $('#contents');
contents.bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
  ...
});

...

/* other people's code */
var contents = $('#contents');
contents.append(...);
contents.append(...);
...
...
```

I bind to the event 'DOMSubtreeModified', I noticed that my callback function will be called more than 10 times, because many elements are being inserted/modified as separate calls consecutive. I am not able to modify other people's code, and I have no control on how they will implement the append new elements. Is there a way I could make my callback function being called only once *after* all the elements appended/changes?

Comment: set a timer for 100ms and reset it every time

Comment: You can't modify other people code but surely you can force them call a method you expose to them, no ? This looks like a strangely managed project if everybody modifies the DOM without control and without bothering calling a function...

Comment: If you are unable to change anyone else's code it's hard. The best way to do it would be to either add a custom event to be triggered by the piece of code which is appending the elements as that code would know best when it is done or pass a callback method to that code to be called ones it is done appending. But if you can't add to existing code you are not going to have a reliable way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe I should explain why. The reason I couldn't change to other people's code is because this script is for greasemonkey running on a 3rd party site.

Comment: Or, you could just not use DOMSubtreeModified and find another way to do your event. What is your event doing?

Comment: Have you looked at a throttle function (like Ben Alman)'s yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `setTimeout()`. Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/qDD8N/)

```
var timer;
$("#content").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function()
{
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() { alert("finished"); }, 100);
});

$("button").on("click", function()
{
    $("#content").append("<span>FUS</span>");
    $("#content").append("<span> RO</span>");
    $("#content").append("<span> DAH</span>");
});​
```

Comment: @FrançoisWahl No, the timer is reset after every append, so as long as "foreign" code does not take extended amount of time between appends (in which case we probably should trigger event anyway) it will work as a charm.

Comment: Why? Have you looked at the jsfiddle I provided?

Comment: Without an explanation on the **how** I just didn't see how this code actualy works. The fiddle was useless to me as it showed it working but didn't make it clear to me **how**. It took up to now for me to actually get it. I did not know that `timer` is true as long as the delay is ticking and as such it is able to cancel itself each time the event is called. Until off course the last time the event is called in which the delay of the timer runs it's course and executes the method within. Now that it makes sense: +1